# fill a column based on another one in R

Tags: r

I have the following dt:

| col1 | col2. |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |

What I want is :

| col1 | col2. |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |

I tried many things but it didn't work for me? Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `match`

```
df1$col2 <- match(df1$col1, unique(df1$col1))
```